# ranking dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

Im trying to rank values in columns and assign the ranks to the values from the first column `['Tickers']` . For some columns I want to rank smaller values higher and for `['Dividend']` would rank normally
and preferably store those ranks in new dataframe
So lets say I have this dataframe:

```
    Ticker  P/E     P/S     P/B    P/FCF    Dividend
No.                     
1   NTCT    457.32  3.03    1.44    26.04   -
2   GWRE    416.06  9.80    5.33    45.62   -
3   PEGA    129.02  4.41    9.85    285.10  0.0128
4   BLKB    87.68   4.96    14.36   41.81   0.0062
```

First I replace missing values with 0

```
 df=df.replace('-',0)
```

Then I would rank them and create new dataframe:

```
    Ticker  P/E   Dividend  
No.                     
1   NTCT    4        3
2   GWRE    3        3
3   PEGA    2        1 
4   BLKB    1        2
```

I was thinking about using scipy stats rankdata on columns (i.e: `rankdata(df['P/E'], method='ordinal')`) but it returned error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NavigableString'
```

Comment: Have you tried the [`.rank()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) method available for DataFrames?

Comment: Aside: the NavigableString mention makes me think that you have data coming in from BeautifulSoup or someplace.  Did you parse HTML?  You should make sure that you use Python strings (or numbers, if the strings represent numbers) instead in DataFrames, you'll get some weird behaviour otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Craig said in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43297408/ranking-dataframe-columns/43297617#comment73660457_43297408) you can use [DataFrame.rank(method='dense')](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) method:

```
df.Dividend = pd.to_numeric(df.Dividend, errors='coerce').fillna(1)
df[['Ticker']].join(df[['P/E','Dividend']].rank(method='dense'))
```

Explanation (step by step):

```
In [35]: df
Out[35]:
    Ticker     P/E   P/S    P/B   P/FCF Dividend
No.
1     NTCT  457.32  3.03   1.44   26.04        -
2     GWRE  416.06  9.80   5.33   45.62        -
3     PEGA  129.02  4.41   9.85  285.10   0.0128
4     BLKB   87.68  4.96  14.36   41.81   0.0062

In [36]: df.Dividend = pd.to_numeric(df.Dividend, errors='coerce').fillna(1)

In [37]: df
Out[37]:
    Ticker     P/E   P/S    P/B   P/FCF  Dividend
No.
1     NTCT  457.32  3.03   1.44   26.04    1.0000
2     GWRE  416.06  9.80   5.33   45.62    1.0000
3     PEGA  129.02  4.41   9.85  285.10    0.0128
4     BLKB   87.68  4.96  14.36   41.81    0.0062

In [38]: df[['Ticker']].join(df[['P/E','Dividend']].rank(method='dense'))
Out[38]:
    Ticker  P/E  Dividend
No.
1     NTCT  4.0       3.0
2     GWRE  3.0       3.0
3     PEGA  2.0       2.0
4     BLKB  1.0       1.0
```

Comment: Should be `'coerce'` -- `'coerse'` only works by accident as a fallthrough, if I'm reading the code correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the [rank method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html):

```
df.rank(method='min', ascending=False)
```

You can then pick the columns you want and take it from there to make your new DataFrame.